# Reading GZIP File Causing Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream in java

Tags: java, json, gzip

I am converting GZIP byte array to String form in Java.This is considerably large file and idea is to convert this in to JSON.

But Exception I am getting is quite weird and is not making much Sense.

Code Snippeet:

```
public static String convert(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        final byte[] BUFFER = new byte[16234];

        GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int len;
        while ((len = gzipInputStream.read(BUFFER)) >= 0) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(BUFFER, 0, len);
          if(byteArrayOutputStream.size ()>60812918){
                System.out.println ( "stopping here" );
            }
        }

        byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();

        gzipInputStream.close();

        final byte[] dataPart = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        String data = new String(dataPart, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        return data;
    }
```

Exception Trace:

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:117)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at com.here.rcs.discoverkernels.testS3FileReader.convert(testS3FileReader.java:84)
    at com.here.rcs.discoverkernels.testS3FileReader.viewJson(testS3FileReader.java:45)
    at com.here.rcs.discoverkernels.testS3FileReader.main(testS3FileReader.java:21)
```

From Coding point of view,I don't think there is something wrong with this piece of code.

Any Suggestions how to move forward with this.

Adding To Byte Conversion Part;

```
public static byte[] compress(final String data) throws IOException {

    final byte[] dataPart = data.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    gzipOutputStream.write(dataPart);

    gzipOutputStream.flush();
    gzipOutputStream.close();

    byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Your title refers to a zip file; the body of your question refers to gzip. These are different formats - could you clarify which you're actually using?

Comment: Either you are reaching `stopping here` or the input is incomplete.

Comment: Sorry For confusion.It is gzip

Comment: Is the .gz file correct? Can you open it using other tools?

Comment: Yes I can.This file was uploaded to S3 from a different java process.ETag value of S3 File(which is mostly MD5 ,except in certain cases) is same what I downloaded in my running application.MD5 (27654994_MEA_BW_1901-1-32.json.gz) = d611c8a45a6fbc23dcc870dcf9c770e1

Comment: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home is java version

Comment: How was the byte array populated? More to the point, *why* was the byte array populated? This won't scale to large files. The parameter to the method should be an input stream, not a byte array, or possibly even a filename. Your question is not complete without this information. The calling code must be posted here, in your question, not as a link, and all four of your existing links are irrelevant.

Comment: Re your edit: Your question mentions a *file*. ***How was the file read into the `String`?*** You keep leaving out critical information. And *why* was it read into a String? It should have been read directly into a byte array, or better still the `GZipInputStream` should have been wrapped directly around a `FileInputStream`. All this extra code is pointless.

Comment: To sum it all up: 'I am converting GZIP byte array to String form in Java': why?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your program with a small .gz file, and it works as expected. I guess that

1. there are issues handling large files, or, more likely,
2. you did not loaded correctly data from file to `bytes` array. How did you? I followed this article: https://netjs.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-to-convert-file-to-byte-array-java.html

Comment: It works with small files(This is running in production for some time).Data is loaded correctly in to bytes.As I mentioned, this happens towards the end of large file.I don't know what constitutes large file.I have observed one fascinated behaviour during debug course.I will be shortly updating my findings

Comment: I have added image links for debug screen shot of code.Thing to figure out is how does stack call changes from Manifest$FastInputStream to InflaterInputStream

Comment: I am catching this exception and moving ahead for time being but will keep question open

Comment: @MrWayne You haven't answered his question. How was the byte array filled? You need to post that code, here, in your question. All four of your links are irrelevant. Your question isn't complete or answerable without this information.

Comment: Compression part  is updated in question.It is pretty standard .AS I said earlier as well,this is running in production